# LyX interface too large

Tags: lyx

I am having a problem with LyX on my laptop. I am running Windows 10 at a resolution of 3840x2160. When I open LyX, the interface is simply too large: [image]

So large in face, I can't even "apply" any preferences I change in the dialog box.

Please advise on how to reduce the interface size. I can't even right click on the preferences window, click "move", and drag it around to display the apply button.

Thanks,
C

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you contacted the lyx helpdesk about your issue?

Comment: May be reducing the Screen fonts or changing the Display could do the trick.

Comment: Do you have a HiDPI screen or anything non-conventional?

Comment: Try to fix in Tools → Preferences...→ Look & Feel → Screen Fonts. If you cannot see some fields, move from one field to another using the TAB key, not the mouse. The same to press  the  buttons `Restore` `OK`  and `Apply`.  You can move from "Screen Fonts" to last button (Cancel) in exactly 18 TAB pounds, so for `Apply` the count is 17, and so on. If possible, test it first in another computer.

Answer (score 1):

first thank you everyone for contributing. I did try several of the suggested replies, but ultimately I had to uninstall LyX and reinstall it. It worked immediately (though I had to reestablish some preferences).

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Windows 10 with LyX and also Texniccenter (this problem occured after a java update), and I solved it in the following way:

1. First go to display settings and "Change the size of text..."  to something else than what you have now (I changed from 200% to 100%").
2. Sign out
3. Log in and change back to the same settings that you had before, and sign out again.
4. If you sign in now, it should be fixed.

Comment: I tried changing the text size but didn't sign out and in, I'll try this next time if it acts up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tools>Preferences>Look&Feel>Screen fonts>Default zoom can solve this.